# executable file is not compatible with win10 after gen cmake and run make

Tags: c++, cmake

I am a newbie in cmake. I try to write an simple c++ and cmake to print "Hello world"

Here is my c++ code: HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/TCC/Tools/greenhills_ifx/comp_201815_5fp_WIN64/cxtri.exe")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/TCC/Tools/greenhills_ifx/comp_201815_5fp_WIN64/cctri.exe")
project (hello)

add_executable(hello HelloWorld.cpp)
```

I can generate cmake and run make successful. The final output is hello.exe file. But when I run hello.exe it said error.

[image]

My PC is windown10 - 64 bit. When I check this exe file it only support maximum win8
[image]

My question is how can I run this exe in win10? Is there any specific configuration for cmake to generate .exe that run in win10?

**More info:**

My PC use win10-64 bit

Cmake I use Unix MakeFiles

Compiler I use greenhills_ifx/comp_201815_5fp_WIN64/cxtri.exe for cpp

Cmake generate successful
[image]

make generate successful
[image]

But I can't run .exe file

Comment: If you use that toolchain to manually build, does the program work?

Comment: When you run the CMake program, what is the output it generates? What is the output generated when building your program? And what version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: which's toolchain? Do you mean qnx_build_tools/2.0.629.S201802061654v1_WIN64/qnx700/host/win64/x86_64/usr/bin/make.exe? My problem is I want to run hello.exe in windown 10. It's always said error incompatible 64 ...

Comment: The toolchain is C:/TCC/Tools/greenhills_ifx/comp_201815_5fp_WIN64/cxtri.exe.  I suspect it's not emitting Win10-compatible executables, at least by default.

Comment: *it only support maximum win8* - it's oblivious, the compatibility mode is for the previous versions of Windows, Windows 8 is the newest Windows prior Windows 10.

Comment: Stephen already said it, I don't think that CMake is the problem, but much rather your toolchain. Have you tried it with the VS toolchain, or Mingw?

Comment: I tried with Mingw but the same issue. I guess the problem like Stephen said. comp_201815_5fp_WIN64/cxtri.exe is not support for windown 10.

Comment: Problem is here - _"Unsupported __16 bit__ application"_.  MS Windows 10 64-bit native and supports 32-bit in a sort of VM mode.  No Support for 16-bit executables.  Either (a) play with the your compiler switches or (b) get a supported compiler.  My suggestion is Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition - free download from MS.

Comment: Is there any way to get support from compiler to change it from 16 bit application to 64bit/32 bit application?

Comment: Please provide a link to your compilers support / documentation pages.

Comment: The document name is "MULTI: Building Applications for Embedded TriCore" pdf file. I am sorry but I can't find any this pdf file in website. It's belong to https://www.ghs.com/products/TriCore_development.html

Comment: That's a compiler (and tool-chain) for an embedded development system https://www.ghs.com/products/compiler.html I strongly suggest you don't use it for anything other than it's intended purpose -  embedded micro-controllers.